# How to Troubleshoot Jitter in Unity - Vive VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, resources, htc-vive

Update: 
Shadows! It looks like the biggest problem I had was with shadows. I had absolutely every mesh giving and receiving shadows. Turning off shadows seems to reduce my issues by 99%. Not sure what the remaining 1% is, but this is way better! So on that note, my question still remains, how the heck could I have known it was shadows? Surely the graph below should have somehow told me this, yes?

Original Question:
The main question is how can I troubleshoot this further? I know there's a profiler thing but I'm not sure what to do with it. Is that what I want and need? Does this tell anyone anything? It should be representative of when the jitter is occurring.

[image]

More Background: I use a Vive controller to move by pulling the trigger. I perform a transform based on Time.DeltaTime using the vector position of the controller minus the y axis to know which way to move and how fast. There are tons of enemies and tons of spherical trees. The game seems to run quite well except when I look towards a particular direction. In trying to isolate what it is in that direction, I started turning stuff off such as enemies and the trees. Oddly enough, it makes it WORSE. The only way I can imagine this to be possible is if something is eating up resources all the more now that it's no longer fighting for them with other objects. But it would have to be doing it outside the regular frame loop or else the movement wouldn't appear impaired at all, right? That, or it's something wrong with how I move which now has more processing power to make it worse? I'm so at a loss. Anything wrong with this strategy?

```
public override void OnTriggerPulled(float triggerPullPercent)
{
    if (!mainHand && triggerPullPercent > 0.05)
    {
        Vector3 goForward = transform.forward;
        goForward.y = 0;
        transform.parent.transform.Translate(goForward * triggerPullPercent * Time.deltaTime * 5f);
    }
}
```

Even worse, the issue is inconsistent. After removing all the trees and seeing zero signs of improvement, I removed a single object just cuz it was ugly and not ready for the game anyway. Suddenly, things seemed quite a bit better than the "Worse" state it was in but it was more akin to the original jittery state which had me doing this to begin with. I added the object back in and oddly enough, it did not revert back to its worse state. So clearly it must not have been the object that made it any better/worse. I added my trees back in and it was suddenly back to the horrendous state. Now suspecting the trees, I removed them again and found no difference. Still crappy. So... not the trees or the object? I removed the one object and it was suddenly much better again. I can do this forever very repeatably. What gives? It's neither and both simultaneously? Any ideas? What more can I do to troubleshoot this? My current method is severely lacking.

Thanks!

Comment: Somethings that can cause jitter is the editor itself. Try playing when the game view is maximized and the profiler has Deep Profile disabled. You can also try to build the game and run it.

Comment: Didn't think of that. I just built and ran it. It seems faster in general, but the same problem area causes jitter still. I really need to isolate what is causing it :-\.

Comment: @JohanLindkvist See my update above. It appears to have something to do with lighting. Any ideas?